# segmentation fault with a game of life function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a segmentation fault in this function and I have no idea why. I can't isolate the problem with GDB, it just tells me this is the function that fails and I'm just looking to see if anyone sees something immediately wrong. I'm trying to learn C and optimize this function. It's a function for cell evolution for an implementations of Conway's game of life.

I call two other functions within this one that return the number of neighbors a cell has. The board is a 2d array, of WIDTH and HEIGHT.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the function:

```
void evolveCell(board prev, board next)
{
  int i, j, n, mask;
   int width = WIDTH;
   int height = HEIGHT;

 for (i=1; i < width-1; ++i) {
      for (j = 1; j < height-1; ++j) {
         n = _neighbors(prev, i, j);
         mask = (prev[i][j] << 1);
         next[i][j] = !(((n >> prev[i][j]) ^ 3) ^ mask);
      }
   }

   for (i = 0; i < width; i+= width-1) {
     prev[i][j] = prev[i][0];
     next[i][j] = next[i][0];
     for (j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
       n = neighbors(prev, i, j);
       mask = (prev[i][j] << 1);
       next[i][j] = !(((n >> prev[i][j]) ^ 3) ^ mask);
     }
   }
   for (j = 0; j < height; j += height-1) {
     prev[i][j] = prev[0][j];
     next[i][j] = next[0][j];
     for (i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
       n = neighbors(prev, i, j);
       mask = (prev[i][j] << 1);
       next[i][j] = !(((n >> prev[i][j]) ^ 3) ^ mask);
     }
   }
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the definition of `board`?

Comment: Well, given all the array indexing going on, I am guessing it is an out of bound condition.

Comment: Updated, it's a 2d array.

Comment: regarding this line: 'void evolveCell(board prev, board next)'   I suspect the two parameters should be pointers to the two instances of board, I.E. do not try to pass the board instance, because in C, passed parameters are always by value, so the code will be only changing copies of the two instances of the board, NOT the actual board instances.

Comment: there are several subtle problems with using a leading underscore in function and variable names.  Suggest changing name to 'neighbors'

Comment: in general, the game of life ALL depends on the number of neighbors.  So call the neighbors() function for each location in 'board'  then use a switch statement on the returned value from neighbors() to determine if the 'next' at the same location is to be dead or alive.   This requires a nested for loop , a call to neighbors, and a switch statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect there's some issue with your line

```
 for (j = 0; j < height; j += height-1) {
     prev[i][j] = prev[0][j];
```

Consider the previous for loop, for a value of say width = 3. i evolves as 0, 2, 4. When `i` becomes 4, that for loop is not used, but the value of i is now 4 and then the next for loop, one mentioned above is used and when you are trying to access `prev[4][0]`, there's likely a problem.

With gdb - you can do a backtrace (bt) that tells you exactly which line is causing a problem. For that you are advised to compile with '-g' option (I am assuming gcc) or refer your compiler's manual for enabling debug symbols. That will tell you the line that's causing problem and then using variable prints (`p i`, `p j`) on your gdb prompt you'd be able to debug the actual issue.

Hope that helps